# libxml for C++: How to add a root node to XML tree?

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, libxml2

I have an xml file that looks like the following

```
<siteinfo>
...
</siteinfo>
<page>
   <title>...</title>
   <revision>
   ...
   <revision>
</page>
```

It does not have a root/enclosing node so I get the "extra content at end of document" on running my program. After opening the file for parsing using libxml, is there a way to easily add this root/enclosing node to the parse tree?

Comment: Is it possible to change XML writer? I think that it'll be better to make it XML conformant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't change the structure of the source XML, an easier way would be to create a string like:

```
string xml = string("<root>") + file_contents + string("</root>");
```

Then you can parse this string easily. By the way, since you're using C++, you should give libxml++ a try. It is a C++ wrapper for libxml and it is very good.

Comment: Thanks. So it is possible to parse a string rather than a file? If so, your answer is exactly what I need :-)

Comment: It is possible with libxml++, so it obviously should be possible with libxml, which is the base library.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was using libxml++. Apparently not. I had to install so many packages, I lost track. Will stick with libxml2 until I find libxml++ to be much easier ;-). Thanks again.